# What are some best practices for inbound email handling with CiviCRM?

Tags: email, civicase

Our organization has grown past the point where one person can handle the inbound e-mail from our members.  I'm looking for best practices from the community on how to handle this.

We don't want to give all of our staff access directly to the e-mail account.  As staff come and go, we would have to connstantly change the password to that account.  Also, giving everyone direct access to the account would require a tagging system to know who is handling what message.  This seems less than ideal.

We could adopt a ticketing system, either something like osTicket or something like Zendesk.  But I think it would be nice to have all of our interactions with our members in one clear place.  After all, isn't that what a CRM is supposed to do for you?

I looked at CiviCase and at first glance it appears to be exactly right.  But for some reason [out of the box CiviCRM does not create a new case for each new inbound e-mail](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24164/how-do-i-automatically-create-a-case-on-inbound-email).  Discovering this got me thinking that perhaps opening a case for each inbound e-mail is not the right approach?

So I'm looking for input from the community: for those of you who have grown past the point of 1 or 2 staff to handle inbound email, what do you do to capture the email and respond to it?

Thank you

EDIT:
I looked at CiviRules, but unfortunately it lacks some conditions and some actions to make this possible:

- I could say "Take an action when an activity of type Inbound Email is received"
- But I could not say that the action should be to create a case.
- Presumably I also could not say to assign the activity to the case.
- I also could not say "Only take this action if the activity is not already associated with a case" (e.g. if the email subject has a case ID)

Comment: One of the orgs I know does use a type of tagging system to know who is handling, but they also have a designated daily person who is the default handler for that day so that everything gets handled. But to-date all the installations I've worked with have always involved at least some custom code to integrate with how the org works.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to explore is if CiviRules has a 'create case' capability that could be triggered from creating an Activity, which itself had been created by inbound email

Comment: Unfortunately CiviRules lacked the necessary conditions and triggers.  I added some details in an edit to my original question.

Comment: Then I would think the solution is an extension that would eg work on basis that an email to email address X should trigger a new case, assign to default Coordinator etc if no #caseid is in the subject. doesn't sound like a big job

Comment: also did you read this? https://civicrm.org/blog/dahndy/leveraging-civicrm-email-to-activity-processing-in-gmail in case it adds any new thoughts

Comment: fyi we did some improvements to Inbound Email so #caseid works in case that gives you some ideas: https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/improvements-to-inbound-emails-to-cases-in-4730

Comment: oh. sorry that was to core not via an extension